# Post method is not executed when get method is invoked by ModelAndView from different method.

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, modelandview

I need help.

Post method is not executed when get method is invoked by ModelAndView from different method.

Get method for mapping2 is correctly populated with data(taken from ModelAttribute), but
when I'm pressing form Submit button it is not executing post method for mapping2. It's running GET method all the time.

Url is mapping1 and it is not changing to mapping2, just jsp for mapping2 is displayed as content of mapping1.

Do you have any idea how to run post method?

The code from controller below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mapping1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addItem(
        @RequestParam(value = "year", required = true) final BigDecimal year,
        @ModelAttribute("item") final Item item,
        final HttpServletRequest request) {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("mapping2");        
    mav.addObject("item", item);

            return mav;
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/mapping2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Item addItemConfirmation(
        @ModelAttribute("item") final Item item,
        final HttpServletRequest request) {

    return item;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/mapping2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addItemConfirmation(
        @ModelAttribute("Item") final Item item,
        final HttpServletRequest request) {

            operations on item...

    itemDAO.persist(item);                      

    return "redirect:/itemAddSuccess
```

}

Comment: are you sure your html form specifies `method="post"`?

Comment: Please post your form html code

Comment: Using FireFox or Chrome you should be able to verify that the POST is being sent.  My guess is that you are doing a GET.

Comment: Hi, 
yes I am using method="post". My jsp is as following: 

<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="item" >
  <ul>
   <li><label>name</label> <form:input path="name"
     ...
 <div class="form-buttons">
  <input type="submit" value="Save"> 
 </div>
</form:form>

Comment: Where's the form action?